# Server - Lightweight GUI for 20.04 - only need browser, copy files, and see terminal windows

Tags: command-line, server, gui, 20.04, rabbitmq

I've looked at a LOT of articles and suggestions, and tried a few options, but i'm super confused as there is a lot of conflicting and constantly changing advice.

We are moving from windows server 2016 to Ubuntu, due to this transition we need to limit the amount of change, mainly moving from a GUI to command line.
The server will need RabbitMq, and run C# dotnet core console apps (10 microservices that all use Rabbitmq to communicate)

We need an extremely light weight gui that has a browser so we can download file/see rabbitmq management screen, and ability to have multiple terminal windows running so we can see the output of each microservice
We will also need to copy and paste files for new releases

Currently these microservices are EXE files on windows, and an app called restartOnCrash keeps them running, we need a similar scenario so we can have these console apps running and detect if they are not (and something will need to make sure they are running, not sure what options there are here)

As we all get use to the linux environments, we will remove the GUI, but for now we need one so the transition is less risky and more familiar for everyone

When there are system issues, we look at RabbitMQ ingestion rates, queue sizes, and each microservice console app to determine where the issue is, so we need to retain this visibility and workflow.

Can anyone suggest a lightweight GUI that is low on system resources to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at hosting a webgui instead such as [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) or [Webmin](https://www.webmin.com)?

I apologize, I realize this is 5 months or so late. I hope you found a solution!